# How to make looking good TextMesh text

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, pixelate

I need to show good looking text
I generate large text texture but text looks pixelated ((
How to fix this?

[image: See pixelated image here]

Answer (score 0):

Change the texture type to GUI and set its format to TrueColor
You can find the settings in the inspector once you select the texture